# Stat_function will not accept a list of parameters (ggplot)

Tags: r, list, function, ggplot2

I am trying to get ggplot to plot a function, e.g.

```
library(ggplot2)
dframe <- data.frame(x = c(0:30), y = c(0:30 * 10))
LVB = function(t, Linf, K, t0) {
Linf*(1-exp(-K*(t-t0)))
}
parms = list("Linf" = 209, "K" = 0.47, "t0" = -1.61)
g = ggplot(dframe, aes(x, y))
   g = g + stat_function(fun = function(x) LVB(x, 200, 0.6, -1), color = "red")
g
```

[image: Plot with red function]

But I'd like to be able to store the parameters of my "LVB" function in a list - here, I've defined them, but usually they would come from a model:

```
parms = list("Linf" = 209, "K" = 0.47, "t0" = -1.61)
```

I want to get the following line (my model parameters) added to the plot so it looks like this:

```
   g + stat_function(fun = function(x) LVB(x, 209, 0.47, -1.61), color = "blue")
```

[image: desired plot]

But, no matter what I do, stat_function won't take my list... what am I missing here??

```
 g + stat_function(fun = function(x) LVB(x, parms), color = "blue")
g
```

> Warning message: Computation failed in `stat_function()`: argument "K"
>   is missing, with no default

### -----------

**EDIT:**
Stibu answered this and provided a good solution. Reading up on the functions in the "FSA" package I thought this one might also do the trick - it asks for the length of the argument and if it's three, it defines each parameter. Sneaky but effective.

```
LVB = function(t, Linf, K, t0) 
   {
   if (length(Linf) == 3) {
        K <- Linf[[2]]
        t0 <- Linf[[3]]
        Linf <- Linf[[1]]
    }
Linf*(1-exp(-K*(t-t0)))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `stat_function()` but rather with `LVB()` itself. You have defined it with the syntax

```
LVB(t, Linf, K, t0)
```

and you have to respect this. If you run

```
LVB(t, parms)
```

the function thinks that it should use `parms` for `Linf` and considers `K` and `t0` as missing, which is why you get an error.

You can use `do.call()` to get around this. `do.call()` can be used to pass function arguments to as a list. So the following three lines are equivalent

```
LVB(3, 5, 2, 1)
do.call(LVB, list(3, 5, 2, 1))
do.call(LVB, list(t = 3, Linf = 5, K = 2, t0 = 1))
```

You can use this in `stat_function()` as follows:

```
g + stat_function(fun = function(x) do.call(LVB, c(list(x), parms)), color = "blue")
```

Alternatively, you could also change your function definition:

```
LVB_list <- function(t, parms) {
  parms$Linf*(1-exp(-parms$K*(t-parms$t0)))
}
g + stat_function(fun = function(x) LVB_list(x, parms), color = "blue")
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, @Stibu! Can you explain why LVB(x, parms) doesn't work?

Comment: The function `LVB` expects four arguments and you only supply two. Compare `LVB()` and `LVB_list()`. For the latter `LVB_list(x, parms)` works, but as you can see, the function definition is different.

Comment: I really appreciate your edited answer, @Stibu: it's so much better to understand what's going on under the hood. Thanks for taking the time here.